ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_client'
I'm trying to install the Java kernal for Jupyter notebook so I can run Java from Jupyter notebook as detailed here:
https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-use-jupyter-notebook-for-java-a-comprehensive-guide/
I have Jupyter notebook, installed through Anaconda, but when I run the installer, from Anaconda prompt, I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_client' and I am not sure what to do to fix it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<filepath>\Downloads\ijava-1.3.0\install.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.kernelspec import KernelSpecManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_client'

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I haven't been able to find or figure out a solution.
I've tried updating Anaconda, Jupyter notebook, and searching for other solutions online.

I fixed the same issue with both pip install jupyter_client and conda install jupyter_client.
